# Selenium - Navigation gets stuck after clicking a drop down (prior to an iframe switch)

Tags: selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, html-table

The code clicks and pops up an overlay (successful). I am able to switch to iframe (using the `driver.switchTo().frame(2)`). Once selecting an element and clicking the Accept button, the overlay closes. Now I switch back to the main page using `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()`. The problem occurs soon after the code clicks a dropdown in the main page. This dropdown is not the typical Select or Option type (`Select()` or `<option>`). The elements are listed in a `<table>`.

There is no error displayed in the console but the program hangs. It stops the navigation after clicking the drop down and then no response.

Please find the html portion:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cph$ctl02$TEST$FORM$ctl06$ctl32$ctl01$ctl03"
    id="ctl00_cph_ctl02_TEST_FORM_ctl06_ctl32_ctl01_ctl03" />
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cph$ctl02$TEST$FORM$ctl06$ctl32$ctl01$ctl04"
    id="ctl00_cph_ctl02_TEST_FORM_ctl06_ctl32_ctl01_ctl04" value="-1" />
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cph$ctl02$TEST$FORM$ctl06$ctl32$ctl01$ctl05" />
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cph$ctl02$TEST$FORM$ctl06$ctl32$ctl01$ctl06" />
<div id="ctl00_cph_ctl02_TEST_FORM_ctl06_ctl32_ctl01_outerFrame"
    class="DropdownOuterContainer theme2 boarderA font7 shadow1" style="display:none;">
    <div id="ctl00_cph_ctl02_TEST_FORM_ctl06_ctl32_ctl01_innerFrame"
        class="DropdownInnerContainer" style="z-index:99;">
        <table id="ctl00_cph_ctl02_TEST_FORM_ctl06_ctl32_ctl01_tbl"
            class="DropdownItemContainer" list="120">
            <tr class="">
                <td value="" index="0" title="">&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td class="BorderCell"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td value="Act1" index="1" plid="1001">Act1</td>
                <td class="BorderCell"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td value="Act2" index="2" plid="1002">Act2</td>
                <td class="BorderCell"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td value="Act3" index="3" plid="1003">Act3</td>
                <td class="BorderCell"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td value="Act4" index="4" plid="1004">Act4</td>
                <td class="BorderCell"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

In the code I am trying to select an option 'Act1' using the below statements. Note that only the first line executes, i.e, it clicks the drop down but then it doesn't move forward to the next step, where the selection happens.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_cph_ctl02_TEST$FORM_ctl06_ctl32_ctl01']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_cph_ctl02_TEST$FORM_ctl06_ctl32_ctl01_tbl']/tbody/tr/td[1][contains(text(),'Act1')]")).click();
```

Comment: I suspect that the frame switching has nothing to do with this issue.  A couple of questions:  can you confirm that there isn't a problem with the application under test...if you manually follow the same steps all's well?  Also, have you tried adding an explicit wait for the Act1 option before the attempt to click?  that might tell you something.

Comment: You might also change your selector to work on the "value" attribute: driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_cph_ctl02_TEST$FORM_ctl06_ctl32_ctl01_tbl']/tbody/tr/td[value='Act1')]"))

Comment: @BreaksSoftware Doing it manually is all good with no issues. Moreover, I am still facing the same issue when I add Wait. 
Also, to note that, if I skip the overlay part (which involves the iframes), and directly go to the drop down element, the code is able to identify the drop down and also is able to click the selected element (Act1) - which means it is executing the second statement successfully.

Comment: I don't know.  perhaps the action in the "overlay" is causing something to happen to the page to move items around?  the xpath for Act1 is very specific...did you try my alternative?  It would be more helpful if you could provide us with a link to the actual page.